# Kubernetes helm waiting before killing the old pods during helm deployment

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-helm

I have a "big" micro-service (website) with 3 pods deployed with Helm Chart in production env, but when I deploy a new version of the Helm  chart,  during 40 seconds (time to start my big microservice) I have a problem with the website `(503 Service Unavailable)`

So, I look at a solution to tell to kubernetes do not kill the old pod before the complete start of the new version

I tried the `--wait --timeout` but it did not work for me.

My EKS version : "v1.14.6-eks-5047ed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details about the Pods, I'd suggest:

Use [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) (if not already) so that Pods are managed by a Replication Controller, which allows to do [rolling updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/), and that *in combination* with [configured](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) Startup Probe (if on k8s v1.16+) or Readiness Probe so that Kubernetes knows when the new Pods are ready to take on traffic (a Pod is considered ready when all of its Containers are ready).

Comment: the problem is my EKS version : "v1.14.6-eks-5047ed"

Comment: [Rolling updates](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/) and [Readiness Probe](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) are supported on v1.14. So I would also recommend using this approach.

Comment: +1 on the above answer; except the mention to "Replication Controller" is incorrect (Replication Controller is an obsolete mechanism, that was superseded by the combo Deployment + Replica Set). Other than that: yes, use a Deployment + a Readiness Probe (perhaps with an initialDelaySeconds parameters).

Comment: I'd also add: set the maxUnavailable to 0, so that new pods are started before old ones are deleted.